# Catch left-click, let right-click pass through

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have an element that I want to be able to right click. However, above that element are several elements that are transparent and I want to be able to left click (to know where has been clicked). Is there a way to make the right-clicks hit the element below, while the left clicks are still registered by the transparent elements above?

Comment: show a bit of code

Comment: This link should help you create example code to put in your question so we can see the problem for ourselves: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

One way of tackling this is to prevent the right click having any effect on the transparent element that is on top except for making it dispatch an event on the underneath element.

Here's a simple example.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.underneath {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
.ontop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="underneath" oncontextmenu="alert('underneath');">right click me</div>
<div class="ontop" onclick="alert('ontop');" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();const ev = new Event('contextmenu'); document.querySelector('.underneath').dispatchEvent(ev);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make this work with the default context menu as well, instead of an alert?

Comment: The alert is only there for demo purposes - to prove that the right element is receiving the correct event. Remove it and put in whatever code you want to put in. Also, normally I'd have added the eventListener through Javascript rather than use the onclick/oncontextmenu attributes. I used them also just for the demo.

Comment: I know I can make a custom menu, but I was wondering if I can make the default one appear as well ( the one you would get when clicking somewhere without a `oncontextmenu` listener)